# SQL query - IS NULL

Tags: sql

Tables:

```
Country
-------
PK CountryID

Name

City
-------
PK CityID

FK CountryID

Name

Airport
--------
PK AirportID

FK CityID

Name
```

My task is to select names of countries that have no airport.

I can imagine only one solution with EXCEPT (or MINUS)

```
SELECT Country.Name 
FROM Country EXCEPT (SELECT DISTINCT Country.Name FROM Country, City, Airport 
WHERE City.CountryID = Country.CountryID AND Airport.CityID = City.CityID);
```

But is it possible not to use EXCEPT but something like IS NULL?

Comment: Sure.. an outer join with a null check should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make this query with `IS NULL` try following query:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c56dc/4)

```
select ct.CountryId,max(ct.Name) from Country ct
left join City c on ct.CountryId=c.CountryId
left join Airport a on a.CityId=c.CityID
group by ct.CountryId
HAVING max(a.AirportID) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT cn.CountryID 
  FROM Country cn
  LEFT JOIN City ct ON cn.CountryID = ct.CountryID
  LEFT JOIN Airport ar on ar.CityID=ct.CityID
 WHERE ar.AirportID is null
```

Comment: I think this query also returns Countries where Airports exist but also Cities without Airports exist.

Comment: Thanks Valex, thanks for pointing out my mistake. +1 for your right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but it's basically the same thing you have with different syntax.

```
SELECT Country.Name 
FROM Country 
Where Country.Name Not IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Country.Name FROM Country, City, Airport 
        WHERE City.CountryID = Country.CountryID AND Airport.CityID = City.CityID
    );
```